# container class css declaration doesn't work even with !important rule

Tags: css

I try to better understand how CSS works. I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* typography
================== */

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.title span {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  font-size: .9em;
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
  p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 3.7em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}


/* buttons */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: .5em 1.75em;
  color: #00ff6c;
  border-color: #00ff6c;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .button {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .button-small {
    font-size: .7rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .button-accent {
    color: #00ff6c;
    border-color: #00ff6c;
  }
  .button-accent:hover,
  .button-accent:focus {
    background: #00ff6c;
    color: #232323;
  }
}


/* header
================== */

header {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

nav a: hover,
nav a: focus {
  color: #DDD;
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
  }
  nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/* home-hero
================== */

.home-hero {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/XY54RwQY/hero-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10em 0;
  color: #FFF;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .home-hero {
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 35vh;
  }
}


/* hero-home
======================== */

.home-about-textbox {
  background-color: #232323;
  padding: 4em;
  margin: 0 -2.5vw;
  outline: 2px solid #00ff6c;
  outline-offset: -2.5em;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

.home-about-textbox h1 {
  color: #00ff6c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: .75em;
  background: #232323;
  padding: 0 .145em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
  color: magenta;
}

@media (min-width: 25rem) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2 rem;
  }
  .home-about-textbox h1 {
    top: .6em;
    padding: 0 .325em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .home-about {
    background-image: url();
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 10em;
  }
  .home-about-textbox {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 7em;
    outline-offset: -3.75em;
    margin-left: -2.5%;
    top: -5em;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
  .home-about-textbox h1 {
    top: .75em;
    left: 6rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: .75em;
    background: #232323;
    padding: 0 .145em;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: coral;  
font-weight: 100;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Creative Inc.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NFtwcdYg/logo.png" alt="Creative inc. logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="home-hero">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">Making things looks great
        <span>for companies who make great stuff</span>
      </h1>
      <a href="" class="button button-accent">See Our Work</a>
    </div>
  </section>


  <div class="container">
    <section class="home-about">

      <div class="home-about-textbox">
        <h1>Who we are</h1>
        <p>Sit by the fire drink water out of the faucet hide head under banket so no one can see cat is love, cat is life.Knock dish off table eating always hungry so favor packaging over toy.</p>
        <p>
          <srong>Rub face on owner.</srong>Peer out window, chatter at birds, lure then to mouth. Chase ball of string eat a plant, kill a hand, i am the best have secret plans.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, the `home-about-textbox` is defined in three different ways with the class attribute :

```
  `<div class="container">
  <section class="home-about"> for pc media
<div class="home-about-textbox">`for mobile media
```

But the container also selects the "home-hero" section: `<section class="home-hero"> <div class="container">`.

I tried to figure out what is the role of the container. When I select the `.container` in the css style sheet just the "home-about-textbox" becomes blue on the browser so I tried to change color of the container to see if this class truly selects both of the sections( "home-hero" & "home-about-textbox") how it seems to be.

I selected the container again at the end of the code to make sure that nothing else overrides it (the last media declaration is closed) and I styled with crazy colors but nothing change. I even tried !important rule and the style is the same. My question is:

What exactly this container class selects in the code and why I can't style it?

Answer (score 0):

container is a class that is given to a div tag to define your web page size, and all of the other elements should be inside of it so they will have all styles given to their parent ( container)

you use the !important wrong, you should use it this way:

```
background-color: red !important;
```